# Extract tag from string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
xxx<tag1>ABC</tag1>xxxyyyzzz<tag2>MNO</tag2>zzzz<tag1>EFG</tag1>
```

and I need transform this into

```
<tag1>ABC</tag1><tag2>MNO</tag2><tag1>EFG</tag1>
```

I must extract tag and it's inner content only.

I search regexp what delete all the other content

```
$string2 = eregi_replace($reg, $string1)
```

Comment: What if there are nested tags?

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: Has no one picked up on the usage of `eregi`? Alessandro, `eregi` is depreciated.. Since PHP5.3.0, use the regular expression functions in the `preg` family: http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=preg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = "<tag1>ABC</tag1>xxxyyyzzz<tag2>MNO</tag2>zzzz<tag1>EFG</tag1>";

preg_match_all('#<tag[0-9]>(.*?)</tag[0-9]>#i',$str,$result);

print_r($result[0]);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => <tag1>ABC</tag1>
    [1] => <tag2>MNO</tag2>
    [2] => <tag1>EFG</tag1>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$str = "xxx<tag1>ABC</tag1>xxxyyyzzz<tag2>MNO</tag2>zzzz<tag1>EFG</tag1>";
echo preg_replace('/(.*?)(<tag\d+>)(.*?)<\/tag\d+>(.*?)/','$2$3$4', $str);
```

Note: [eregi is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi-replace.php)

Comment: I'm shocked that no one else has mentioned the depreciation of these functions